# Derech g'dilasan: the requirement for mitzva objects to be used in the manner in which they grew

Tags: halacha-theory, midrash, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

The *mishna* quotes Rabbi Yosi ([*Suka* 3:14](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%93)) saying that if one carried a *lulav* in the public domain without thinking on the first day of *Sukos* which was also *shabas* it would not count as a violation of carrying between domains. The rationale in the *mishna* is that the carrier has an obligation to use the *lulav* and therefore is permitted to take it with him in that pursuit.

Ra'av clarifies that this permission only extends as long as the person hasn't discharged the *mitzva* of picking up [and shaking] the *lulav* and is on the way to doing so when moving it around outside. Since the required activity is picking it up, he justifies the possibility of pick it up *without* fulfilling the *mitzva* by holding it upside down.

> משכחת ליה כגון שהפכו, שכל המצות כולן אין אדם יוצא בהן אלא דרך גדילתן שנאמר (שמות כו) עצי שטים עומדים, שעומדים דרך גדילתן

Here he is alluding to the opinion of Abaye quoted in the *g'mara* which says that *all mitzvos* must be performed using objects in the "manner" in which they grew. The prooftext is the command to build walls for the *mishkan* out of beams stood upright - in the direction they grew.

Later codifiers and commentators (e.g. in [*Orach Chayim* 651:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%91)) understand the application of the דרך גדילתן condition to mean that the point on the object that was formerly attached to the ground should be downwards, regardless of what its orientation was while attached. The *Aruch Hashulchan* ([there](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%90#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%9B%D7%95)) refers briefly to the opinion of the Ram"a that the point of attachment needn't be downward with respect to the ground, just with respect to the one holding it(?), and doesn't reject that logic. "דהקפידא היא שבידו יאחזם כדרך גדילתם. אבל מה שמטה אותם – אינו כלום"

Does *derech g'delasan* mean the-direction-in-which-the-plant-grew or upright? How do they know which it is, considering the small and strange set of precedents?

Comment: An example may help illustrate the issue iiuc: should a person hold the lulav differently if taking it while standing on his head?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You post the answer in the SA and AhS and then ask whether it's the direction in which the plant grew despite the SA? (In any case, who holds a lulav the way it grew? Lulavim grow horizontally.)

Comment: @MichaBerger +Double AA - Thanks for your comments! I will try to clarify the question. (I'm no dendrologist but I'm pretty sure all _lulavim_ when they are in their tightly packed _kasher_ state point straight upwards from the tree like [this](https://www.postery.com/eu/palm-retro-poster).) Each of the 4 apparently grows in a different direction and the precedent of _shitim_ trunks is not obviously transferable. I.e. its mode of application is not obvious to me.

Comment: @WAF but do esrogim grow upward from uqetz to pitom?